# Efficiently merge lists chronologically without duplicates?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

Prepare some dummy data to investigate:

```
alist = RandomSample[Table[ToExpression["a" <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, 10000}]];
range = Range[10000];
Do[
 len = RandomInteger[{3000, 10000}];
 select = Sort[RandomSample[range, len]];
 sublists[j] = alist[[select]];
 , {j, 1, 5000}]
```

we have 5000 `sublists` of length between `3000` and `10000` elements `"ai"` in a particular order. I would like to have a function that merges all 5000 `sublists` such that all duplicates are discarded and any `"ai"` appear to the left of `"aj"` if they do so in any of the `sublists`. How can one do this in Mathematica most efficiently?

A tiny example of the above would be:

```
alist = {a1,a3,a2,a5,a4};
sublists[1] = {a1,a5};
sublists[2] = {a3,a2,a5};
sublists[3] = {a1,a2};
```

so that the function `merge` returns:

```
merge[Table[sublists[i],{i,1,3}]]
```

> {a1,a3,a2,a5}

Note that `merge` was not given the actual `alist`.

**EDIT:**

Investigating the `Experimental'ShortestSupersequence` command, let us replace the definition of `alist` above by

```
alist = Table[a[i], {i, 1, 10000}];
```

This creates a list of strictly increasing `a[i]`. Generating the `sublists` from this as above, we get for example

```
seq = Fold[Experimental`ShortestSupersequence, sublists /@ Range[5000]];
seq//Length
```

> 10984

Repeating the steps seems to consistently return a `seq` that is longer than `10000`, while

```
seq // DeleteDuplicates // Length
```

> 10000

To check that all `sublists` contain `a[i]` elements in strictly increasing order, we can do:

```
FreeQ[
 Table[
  tmp = sublists[i] /. a[x_] -> x;
  tmp = tmp[[2 ;;]] - tmp[[;; -2]];
  FreeQ[tmp/Abs[tmp], -1]
  , {i, 1, 5000}]
 , False]
```

> True

The only way how some of the `sublists` might have some elements reversed in inconsistent order with `alist` is if we had `{...,a[i],...,a[j],...}` with `j<i` somewhere, which is ruled out by the above test. So it seems that `Experimental'ShortestSupersequence` is buggy...

Comment: how do yo reconcile (a) _any "ai" appear to the left of "aj" if they do so in alist_ and (b) _alist is not known explicitly_? (Since sublists are independently shuffled they don't contain any information on whether or not "ai" is before "aj" in the unknown `alist`)

Comment: @kglr note that there is a `Sort` after the `RandomSample` of the integers in `range`. This picks elements from `alist` in an ordered way.

Comment: oh i see...  thanks!

Comment: then..  `{a3, a1, a2,a5}`  is also a solution, right?

Comment: @kglr that's right, without knowing `alist` there are several solutions. Finding any of them should be good enough though. You are right, maybe I should describe the merging better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** You can use [`TopologicalSort`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TopologicalSort.html) after turning each list to a list of rules reflecting the ordering of its elements:

```
ClearAll[topoSort]
topoSort = TopologicalSort[Flatten[Thread[Most@# -> Rest@#] & /@ #]] &;

lists = {{a1, a5}, {a3, a2, a5}, {a1, a2}} ;
topoSort @ lists
```

> {a1, a3, a2, a5}

**Timings:** Using a scaled down version of OP's data:

```
SeedRandom[1]
{n, m, k} = {1000, 300, 500};
alist = RandomSample[Table[ToExpression["a" <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, n}]];
range = Range[n];
Do[
  len = RandomInteger[{m, n}];
  select = Sort[RandomSample[range, len]];
  sublists[j] = alist[[select]];
  , {j, 1, k}]

allsublists = Array[sublists, k];

f = mergeChron[allsublists]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 1.14

```
g = merge[allsublists]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 1.1

```
h = topoSort[allsublists]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.313

```
Equal[f, g, h]
```

> True

With `{n, m, k} = {2000, 600, 1000}`, the timings are `9.44`, `5.69` and `1.64` for `mergeChron`, `merge` and `topoSort`, respectively,

**Original answer:** (this needs further work ...)

```
Fold[Experimental`ShortestSupersequence, sublists /@ Range[3]]
```

> {a3, a1, a2, a5}

Also

```
Fold[Experimental`ShortestSupersequence, RotateRight[sublists /@ Range[3]]]
```

> {a1, a3, a2, a5}

In case this produces an output with duplicates we can use

```
DeleteDuplicates @ Fold[Experimental`ShortestSupersequence, sublists /@ Range[5000]]
```

Comment: Somehow, when I apply this to the big example it returns an output that still has duplicates. If I apply `DeleteDuplicates` to it, will it give the desired ordering?

Comment: @Kagaratsch, my rough intuition is that it should not happen if the orderings in all the sublists are consistent (ie, a and b appear  in the same order in all sublists that contain both) . It could happen if a and b appear in different order in two sublists. In any case wrapping with `DeleteDuplicates` fixes the problem. Could you post the smallest example in which the output has duplicates?

Comment: Hmm, I'm pretty sure the code generates all lists in consistent order due to the `Sort` command before the elements are picked...

Comment: Then it is probably some glitch in the`Experimental`ShortestSupersequence` function.

Comment: Seems that way, see edit of my question for some details.

Answer (score 5):

I think the following works but please give it a try with your data. I've tried quite a few random examples and it has worked for all of them.

First, construct a directed graph with edges defined by neighbors in the sublists:

```
allsublists = Array[sublists, 5000];  (* or whatever the max count is *)
G = Graph[Join @@ (BlockMap[Apply[Rule], #, 2, 1] & /@ allsublists)]
```

Next, look at the `GraphDistanceMatrix` and count how many times the symbol `∞` appears in each row:

```
infcount = Count[∞] /@ GraphDistanceMatrix[G]
```

Next, sort the graph vertices according to this `infcount`:

```
alist = SortBy[Transpose[{VertexList[G], infcount}], Last][[All, 1]]
```

All together in one function:

```
merge[L_] := 
  With[{G = Graph[Join @@ (BlockMap[Apply[Rule], #, 2, 1] & /@ L)]},
    SortBy[Transpose[{VertexList[G], Count[∞] /@ GraphDistanceMatrix[G]}], Last][[All, 1]]]
```

## example

The given example is

```
allsublists = Array[sublists, 3]
(*    {{a1, a5}, {a3, a2, a5}, {a1, a2}}    *)
```

Construct the directed neighbor graph:

```
G = Graph[Join @@ (BlockMap[Apply[Rule], #, 2, 1] & /@ allsublists),
  VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Have a look at the graph distance matrix:

```
VertexList[G]
(*    {a1, a5, a3, a2}    *)
GraphDistanceMatrix[G]
(*    {{0, 1, ∞, 1},
       {∞, 0, ∞, ∞},
       {∞, 2, 0, 1},
       {∞, 1, ∞, 0}}    *)
```

count the infinities in each row, i.e., for each vertex we count how many other vertices are unreachable:

```
infcount = Count[∞] /@ GraphDistanceMatrix[G]
(*    {1, 3, 1, 2}    *)
```

sort the vertices by the number of infinities (i.e. by the number of unreachable other vertices):

```
alist = SortBy[Transpose[{VertexList[G], infcount}], Last][[All, 1]]
(*    {a1, a3, a2, a5}    *)
```

Comment: Nice solution with graphs! I was afraid it would be too memory demanding and/or slow, but my 32GB ram turned out to be enough and it finished in just a minute or two. Amazing!

Comment: As @kglr points out, my solution only points out that I didn't know about [`TopologicalSort`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TopologicalSort.html) and computed it "manually". `alist = TopologicalSort[G]` replaces the calculation of `infcount` and `alist`.

Answer (score 4):

Using [`PositionIndex`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PositionIndex.html) and [`Merge`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Merge.html),

```
mergeChron[x_] := Merge[PositionIndex /@ x, Max] // Sort // Keys;
```

**Test**:

Case1:

```
allsublists= {{a1, a5}, {a3, a2, a5}, {a1, a2}};
mergeChron[allsublists]
```

> {a1, a3, a2, a5}

Case2:

```
alist = RandomSample[Table[ToExpression["a" <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, 1000}]];
range = Range[1000];
Do[len = RandomInteger[{450, 1000}];
 select = Sort[RandomSample[range, len]];
 sublists[j] = alist[[select]];, {j, 1, 300}]
```

For `num = 300`, all three of the methods produce the same output. However, that's not the case for `num = 30`. It might be because of the existence of multiple solutions (as discussed in comments).

```
num = 300;
allsublists = Array[sublists, num];
f = mergeChron[allsublists];
g = merge[allsublists]; (*Roman's*)
h = topoSort[allsublists]; (*kglr's*)
f == g == h
```

> True

Answer (score 2):

This is just a comment on the issue with using `` Experimental`ShortestSupersequence `` for this problem. The algorithm repeatedly merges two lists into a new list. This new list will always carry order information for all of the symbols encountered so far, even when insufficient information is available to establish an order. That means the new list will sometimes have the wrong order for the symbols, when further information is processed in a future merge. As an example consider doing your simple example in a different order:

```
Experimental`ShortestSupersequence[{a3, a2, a5}, {a1, a5}]
```

> {a3, a2, a1, a5}

In this step, there is not enough information to decide the relative order of `a1` with respect to either of `a2` or `a3`, so `` Experimental`ShortestSupersequence `` decided that `a1` came after `a2` and `a3`.  However, the subsequent list `{a1, a2}` establishes that `a1` comes before `a2`, so `` Experimental`ShortestSupersequence `` made the wrong choice. Of course, there is no way to make the correct choice before processing the 3rd sublist.

So, the issue is that the algorithm using `` Experimental`ShortestSupersequence `` is bad, not that `` Experimental`ShortestSupersequence `` has a bug.